# SpringBootTest: How to avoid the need of starting a container

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I have SpringBootTests that use `org.testcontainer:postgres` for integration tests.

While thats very useful for tests that involve the database, it's quite useless when the database isn't needed. Let's say, I want to test the `actuator/info` endpoint.

If I don't provide a database, the context won't load.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    ...
    Error creating bean with name 'liquibase'
```

Question: How can I run a SpringBootTest without the need to provide a database?

Comment: If you are using `@SpringBootTest` it will run the whole application, if that needs a database, you will need a database.

Comment: You could theoretically exclude the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`, and that will result in several beans not being created due to a missing `DataSource` (including JPA stuff and repositories). But that won't solve anything because now all your other beans that autowire those repositories cannot be created either.